# "Trigger" on frequent changes with time range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to monitor a particular table in a SQL database, and get notified (email ideally) if there are a large number of changes within any 30 second period (for example). Unsure if this is best done in SQL Server, or by some other method.

I've been hunting and can't seem to find anything relevant and thought I'd ask here to get pointed in the right direction.

So logically, something like this:
If # of Updates or Inserts exceeds 500 within any 30 second timeframe, send email to x@xxxxxx.com

Any thoughts on how best to attack this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would likely be easier to log your changes in a table, and then check the volume of entries in the last *x* seconds in said table, using an agent job.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split this into separate concerns.

Firstly, how do you detect changes? The easiest is a "last updated" column; you can then run a select query on changes since the current time, and compare that to your limiter.

The second question is how you execute that query and send your emails. Your question title mentions triggers - these are specific SQL Server [objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I have a personal dislike of triggers - they are "side effects", and tend to make code hard to understand, and lead to entertaining bugs. In your case, they're probably a bad solution - you want triggers to be incredibly fast, as they hold up your data changes while they execute. Sending an email is probably slower than you want.

The simplest option is probably to use an [agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017) job, scheduled to run at whatever frequency you need. Again, performance may be a challenge here - having a high-load query run every 30 seconds may slow down your database dramatically.

Comment: Thank you. I'll chase this down and get to reading. Appreciate the response(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any audit/log table which keeps track of transactions (Insert, Update or Delete) on that particular table, then it should be fairly easy.

Use SQL server agent job to execute 2 tasks:

1. Execute a script to count the number of transactions on that audit/log table for the last 30 seconds
2. If it exceeds 500, run powershell script/ .exe file to send emails